# How to patch a type at compile time?

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to achieve the dynamic typing required to create a component system of this style in TypeScript?

```
let block = new Entity();
// block.components === {};
block.has(new Position(0, 0));
// block.components === { position: { ... } }
```

Where `Entity#components` does not have an index signature, but rather a strict shape where keys resolve to appropriate component types.

Here's a rough take on an implementation:

```
class Position implements Component {
  name = "position";
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
}

interface Component {
  name: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

class Entity<T={}> {
  components: T;

  has(component: Component) {
    type ExistingComponents = typeof this.components;
    type NewComponents = { [component.name]: Component };
    this.components[component.name] = component;
    return this as Entity<ExistingComponents & NewComponents>;
  }
}
```

There are a number of reasons that this doesn't actually work:

- The `has` method returns the original entity with a modified type, rather than changing the existing type.
- The `NewComponents` type won't compile because it relies on a runtime property (`component.name`).

The other solution I considered was implementing extension as part of the components, so that the names can be static:

```
class Position implements Component {
  name = "position";
  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  static addTo(entity: Entity) {
    type Components = typeof entity.components & { position: Position };
    entity.components.position = new Position();
    return entity as Entity<Components>;
  }
}

let position = new Position(0, 0);
position.addTo(block);
```

But this style feels backwards and it still doesn't solve the problem of not being able to redefine the type without returning a new one.

Is there a way to change the type at compile time through a method call?

Comment: are you trying to pass in the `Position` type to `has` or an instance of `Position` ? `this.components[component.name] = new Component();` this suggests you want to create a new `Position` in `has` not have it passed in, am I right ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Whoops! Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change `Component` to be generic to preserve at compile type the string literal type representing the component name. Then with a bit of conditional types we can achieve the desired result:

```
// T will be the name of the component (ex 'position')
interface Component<T> {
    name: T;
    [key: string]: any;
}
// Conditional type to extract the name of the component (ex: ComponentName<Position> =  'position')
type ComponentName<T extends Component<any>> = T extends Component<infer U> ? U : never;
class Entity<T={}> {
    components: T;
    // TNew is the added component type 
    // We return Entity with the original T and add in a new property of ComponentName<TNew> which will be of type TNew with a mapped type
    has<TNew extends Component<any>>(componentInstance: TNew) : Entity<T & { [ P in ComponentName<TNew>] : TNew }> {
        this.components[componentInstance.name] = componentInstance;
        return this as any;
    }
}

//Usage: 
export class Position implements Component<'position'> {
    readonly name = "position";
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}


export class Rectangle implements Component<'rectengle'> {
    readonly name = "rectengle";
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

let block = new Entity().has(new Position()).has(new Rectangle());

block.components.rectengle //ok
block.components.position // ok
```

Comment: Wow. Haven't come across inference in conditionals, that's slick! Thanks